# Error when trying to create procedure, why do you think that is?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

all.

I've tried creating a procedure in Oracle Apex 5. However, I get this issue 'ORA-24344: success with compilation error'. I assume it's a syntax error. What do you think it is? *generate_password is a working function that produces a random hex value/string.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_user (firstname in varchar2(20), lastname in varchar2(20), email in varchar2(100), area in varchar2(50), privileges in varchar2(2))
AS
e varchar2(100);
BEGIN

e := generate_password;

insert into user_login (user_name, first_name, last_name, creation_date, last_update_date,  user_privileges, user_pwd)

values ( email, firstname, lastname, SYSDATE, SYSDATE, privileges , e); 

END add_user;
```

Comment: Try `e := generate_password() ;`.

Comment: 'ORA-24344: success with compilation error' I've used that function before without the () and it works. Just not the procedure all together. Very strange.

Comment: Please post the actual compilation errors.

Comment: is this what you mean >> ADD_USER PROCEDURE LINE 1 POSITION 42 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following: := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the actual compilation error. I just SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS; on sql command to get the above comment.

Comment: Try using the command `show errors` after compilation. This might provide more information.

Comment: OK!!! Don't define the length of the varchar2 parameters of the procedure. Simply write `VARCHAR2` without size.

Comment: @FDavidov lol that worked. Why did that work though?

Comment: This is the syntax of PL/SQL. If you think about it, it makes much more sense than defining the length of a buffer that is anyway inherited from the calling code. Last, if my comment solved your problem, I'd appreciate if you up-vote it. Thanks.

Comment: @FDavidov i'm not sure how to upvote a comment. Could you repeat it as an answer reply and i'll upvote it.

Comment: Sure. Stay tuned...

Comment: Answer posted as an **answer**.

Comment: If you are going to be coding in PL/SQL you need to get your development tools set up so you can see your compilation errors without manually querying the data dictionary. Oracle provides [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) free, or there are commercial IDEs like [PL/SQL Developer from Allround Automations](https://www.allroundautomations.com/bodyplsqldev.html). This would be just as true for Java or any other programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't define the length of the varchar2 parameters of the procedure. Simply write VARCHAR2 without size.

This is the syntax of PL/SQL. If you think about it, it makes much more sense than defining the length of a buffer that is anyway inherited from the calling code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set maximum length for varchar2 input parameters - this is not the valid syntax.

Try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_user (firstname in varchar2, lastname in varchar2, email in varchar2, area in varchar2, privileges in varchar2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, You should read PLSQL documentation one more time.

1. You don't need to specified length of parameters on Stored Procedure.
2. Oracle recommend using reference parameters within subprograms Like "p_empid employees.employee_id%TYPE".